# Not getting +2 reputation from edits?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, suggested-edits

There are a lot of questions on SE about people not getting +2 reputation for edits after reaching 2k reputation or 500 accepted edits already. However, I am below 2k reputation (1808) and have only 293 accepted edits.

I've edited ~10 question over the last few days, all edits were accepted, but I did not receive any reputation. The posts have not been deleted, so it's not that the points are awarded and then taken away-- they were never awarded in the first place.

Any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although my initial thought below the line may apply to symptoms similar to what you observed, the actual reason is that you recently passed 500 approved edits.

You can see at https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/112447/lambertj?tab=activity&sort=suggestions that you have made 530 suggestions with a few being rejected and a number on posts that were later deleted, which leads to you having recently passed the cap for points earned this way.

I suspect that you were confused, like I was, by the number of edits recorded under IMPACT being currently 295.

I think that the difference between your 530 and 295 needs better documentation and this has been suggested at [“Total number of edits” tooltip should be reworded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267497/total-number-of-edits-tooltip-should-be-reworded)

---

I just checked the [reputation tab on your profile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/112447/lambertj?tab=reputation) and it appears that on:

- **Dec 1** you lost 2 points when a question that you had an approved suggested edit on was deleted by the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion)
- **Nov 30** you gained 2 points when you suggested an edit that was approved
- **Nov 29** you gained 7 x 2 points when you suggested edits that were approved
- **Nov 24** you lost 5 x 2 points when questions that you had approved suggested edits on were deleted by the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion)

I think your suggested edits, when approved, are receiving the expected 2 points.

However, it also seems that when edits that you suggested, and which were also approved, were made on Q&As that were later deleted, then the points gained for those suggested edits are removed.

This latter behaviour is not something that I was aware happened, or maybe I had forgotten that it happened, but I have found some Meta SE Q&As that appear to document it:

- [Do you lose your +2 edit rep if the edited post is subsequently deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78147/do-you-lose-your-2-edit-rep-if-the-edited-post-is-subsequently-deleted)
- [Removed post gives me -2 reputation. What happened?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145242/removed-post-gives-me-2-reputation-what-happened?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I suspect the reason that the software behaves like this is to:

- provide a permanent reward for suggested edits that are on Q&As that the community (including the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion)) deem valuable enough to keep on the site
- provide only a temporary reward for suggested edits that are on Q&As that the community (including the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion)) later decides are not of high enough quality to remain on the site

Comment: Ahhh, OK. That makes sense. I think the difference between the 530 suggestions and the 295 edits under Impact is largely accounted for by edits where I just re-tagged a post. I had noticed previously that, while +2 points are given for retag edits, they don't show up under the number of posts edited under Impact and do not seem to count toward badges like Copy Editor (my count is at 295 for that as well). Because of this, I assumed retag edits also didn't count toward the 500 approved edit cap, but apparently they do. Thanks for looking into this, PolyGeo.